# Java logic operators

Tags: java, if-statement

Pretty simple, Would

```
if(clickedButton == button0 || button1 || button2 || button3 || button4 || button5 || button6 || button7 || button8 || button9)
```

return `true` if I had clicked `button0`, `button1`, or `button2` etc?
 Also, I don't understand why 
    `if(clickedButton == (button0 || button1 || button2)`... etc. doesn't work either. Is it the    same thing (checking for true or false on a JButton) or is something else completely. Mostly  I'm just messing around with parenthesis, so when this thought hit me, I tried it, and I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you try it ?

Comment: You need an `==` for each comparison

Comment: This doesn't look like a situation where you'd even want to use the || operation. You probably want different `if`s `else if`s for each situation, where a different action is assigned to each button

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quicker if-statement: if \`variable\` is "value" or "value"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006214/quicker-if-statement-if-variable-is-value-or-value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that would be a compilation error since it is parsing as

```
if ((clickedButton == button0) || (button1) || (button2) ...
```

and buttons are not booleans.

You must do:

```
if (clickedButton == button0 || clickedButton == button1 ...
```

But an array would be much cleaner, instead of having nine separate button variables. Then you could do this:

```
if (Arrays.asList(buttons).contains(clickedButton)) {
    ...
}
```

Or, if your buttons are stored in an `ArrayList` (or any `List`), it's just

```
if (buttons.contains(clickedButton)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for array/list solution

Comment: +1: A nice solution that _does_ condense on the if-statement, which  minimizes the chance of mistakes/typos!

Comment: Hmmm, `Arrays.asList ...` requires a sequential scan for every invocation - a `Set` would be more elegant.

Comment: That's why I love stackoverflow, each time you think you know the best solution there is someone with even better answer.

Comment: @GyroGearless Do you think that's an appropriate optimisation, even if it wasn't creating the list every time?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline : Maybe i'm a bit old-fashioned, but if i have the choice of solving a problem in O(1) rather than O(n), i'll choose O(1), especially if it's low hanging fruit like replacing a `List` with a `Set`. On the other hand, given todays computers speed and the hopefully limited number of buttons, it will perhaps make no noticeable difference in practise...

Comment: @GyroGearless `n` is 10. The code is simpler if you create the collection with `asList`. You could compute the collection ahead of time, but that's often far, far worse as in the interactive world the setup is typically under more extreme time-pressures and you're dragging this object around for an unnecessary amount of time. Optimising this sort of thing for machine performance is really bad.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. You would have to do

```
if(clickedButton == button0 
    || clickedButton == button1
    || clickedButton == button2 
    || clickedButton == button3
    || clickedButton == button4
    || clickedButton == button5
    || clickedButton == button6
    || clickedButton == button7
    || clickedButton == button8
    || clickedButton == button9)
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

A boolean expression is expected between logical operators.
I assume in your example that button1,...,button9 are not of a boolean type.

Thus this will lead to an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly a better approach would be to modify your action listener (or equivalent). Checking the source of an event tends to lead to messy and fragile code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to compare each variable separately

   `if(clickedButton == button0 || clickedButton == button1 ..... )`
2. Use `equals()` instead of `==`

*Reason*

`equals()` method is present in the `java.lang.Object` class and it is expected to check for the equivalence of the state of objects!. That means, the contents of the objects. Whereas the `==` operator is expected to check the actual object instances are same or not.

Comment: This is perfeclty fine to use `==` to compare buttons.

Comment: For button it is fine. I just remember using equals() is better

Comment: It's certainly good to remember to use `equals()` when appropriate (there are so many questions where the asker incorrectly uses `==` to compare Strings). While not needed in this case, your mention of it certainly is good.

Answer (score 0):

Additional side note: If the type of your button is anything that can be used in a switch-Statement, e.g. ints, longs, String, enums (and your buttons `button0`, ..., `button9` are constants), you can make use of the (often discouraged) *fall-through* mechanism:

```
switch(clickedButton) {
  case button0:
  case button1:
  case button2:
  case button3:
  case button4:
  case button5:
  case button6:
  case button7:
  case button8:
  case button9:
    // do whatever you wish
}
```

In this scenario, the last (commented) line will be executed whenever `clickedButton` is one of `button0`, ..., `button9`.